# ASP.net web-deployment publish with Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2010, web-publishing

**Situation:**

1. I have configured my web.config and web.release.config file , in the below.
2. I have configured Packet and Publish SQL but it is testing wrongly (I use Access but not SQL , all the web form are connected to Access successfully.)
3. When I Publish to web-deployment in the Internet , The error messages happen in the below. ( Hosting provider ,using own PC for tourist accessing to my Webpage)

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBCS"
 connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>)
```

**web.release.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DBCS"
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data      Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"            xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Error message:**

> Error 1 Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'dbFullSql' and
>   path 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb' cannot be created.) Object of
>   type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb' cannot be created. The value
>   'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb' is not a valid connection
>   string or an absolute path. Keyword not supported: 'provider'. 0 0 FYP

---

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment, but I think that the 'Source' path is invalid on the destination server. Maybe try to put the db in your App_Data and change your source to `Source=|DataDirectory|\Web.accdb`.

With this you would not need the transform for your connection string.
I also noticed that you do not change any with the transform in the release config and it it also missing the providerName attribute.

You can do a local file system publish, or preview the transform just to confirm that the transform is working correctly.

Comment: Connectionstring in web.releases.config is different from web.config?              i have though of local file system, but i need to open the web and database in outside home.

Comment: Source path is invalid on the destination server    how to change the source to Source=|DataDirectory|\Web.accdb ... sorry i am so new

Comment: In you project root you should have App_Data folder. If not, right click project > Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_Data. Then move your Access db to that folder. Then change your ConnectionString as I have shown you:
`<add name="DBCS"
 connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Web.accdb"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`